# Multi-party decryption, no central decrypter

Tags: distributed-decryption

Recently a [bank had a costly mistake](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23552680) that resulted in their master private key being exposed.

Through this thread, I learned about multi-party key storage with [Adi Shamir's secret sharing scheme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFY5SyY3IMQ) as the basis, very cool.

In the naive setup, there's still a person/machine that must do the final decryption which knows the full key.

What scheme(s) allows no central decrypter?

A guess I have is two or more 'groups/keys' separately encrypt/decrypt the message so no one group can ever have the keys to the kingdom.

Or is there a way for the final decrypter to decrypt w/o actually knowing the master key such that only one Adi Shamir scheme is necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to give you a hint, but since I cannot write comments under your question, I write it here:

I think you are searching for a scheme that whenever the secret is reconstructed, the participant's keys dont reveal. We have such schemes, please see [this Lecture Note](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eberry/CryptographicProtocols/LectureNotes.pdf) Chaper 6.

---

Lecture Note information: Lecture Notes, Cryptographic Protocols, Version 1.21
September 13, 2016, Berry Schoenmakers

The name of the protocol is: **Threshold Elgamal Cryptosystem**  But the whole chapter that I mentioned is more informative than just this protocol.

Comment: Also for an even better answer, please at least include a sketch of one protocol so one can build some intuition on how they work.

Comment: My understanding of Section 6.3.1 says each party member (Pi) takes their portion of the private key (Xi) and performs a decryption that does produces an output (Di) where `i` is just who they are.

The beauty of the ElGamal scheme is (Di) is a proper partial decryption that can be passed onto the next party member and they can perform their own partial decryption. Once enough members (t+1) doing partial decryptions, you'll get plain text M. Amazing.